# Add microphone in unity for Android platform

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I want to take audio input in my unity application which I am building for Android platform. The code I have added in Start Function is as follows:

```
var audio = GetComponent< AudioSource > ();
audio.clip = Microphone.Start("Built-in Microphone", true, 10, 44100);
audio.loop = true;
while (!(Microphone.GetPosition(null) > 0)) { }
audio.Play();
```

But it is showing the following error:

```
ArgumentException: Couldn't acquire device ID for device name Built-in Microphone
```

I'm referring from [this](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/206485253-How-do-I-get-Unity-to-playback-a-Microphone-input-in-real-time-) post to add microphone. How to resolve this? Also, is there any blog available for doing this end to end?

Comment: Are you testing on an emulator or a real Android device?

Comment: @HumanWrites I'm testing in unity Environment.

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly indicates that it can't find a Microphone device named "Built-in Microphone".  So you should probably see what devices it can find.

Try running the following code in the Start method and see what output you get:

```
foreach (var device in Microphone.devices)
    {
        Debug.Log("Name: " + device);
    }
```

Once you have a list of the devices, then replace "Built-in Microphone" with the name of your desired device.  If "Built-in Microphone" is in the list or you get the same issue with a different device, then you're probably dealing with a permissions issue.